# Zend framework 1 empty array with db select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a problem, this is a part of my controller and it provides me with an empty array:

```
$tifos = $model-> select()->setIntegrityCheck(false) 
                -> from(array('t'=>'tifos'), array('*', 'date'=>'DATE(t.created_at)'))
                -> join(array('u'=>'users'), 'u.id=t.users_id', array('username', 'avatar'))
                -> where('status = ?', $status)
                -> order('likes DESC')
                -> limit(10, 0)->query()->fetchAll()
                ;
```

$model is an instance of a class which extends Zend_Db_Table.

What could cause the problem? I'm using Zend 1.12.

EDIT

Ok, that's what I've got now, my MySQL query:

```
SELECT `t`.*, DATE(`t`.`created_at`) AS `date`, `u`.`username`, `u`.`avatar` FROM `tifos` AS `t` INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.`id`=`t`.`users_id` WHERE (`t`.`status` = 'ok') ORDER BY `t`.`likes` DESC LIMIT 10
```

My DB Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tifos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`users_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` enum('ok','waiting','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'waiting',
`file` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `users_id` (`users_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
`firstname` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
`avatar` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`email_verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`verification_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;
```

Comment: The question name is misleading. On stack it's better to ask another question than editing one question for all problems. DB experts won't read your question even.

Answer (score 0):

Check what are results fo SQL statement in some client like PMA

```php
$oSql = $model-> select()->setIntegrityCheck(false) 
                -> from(array('t'=>'tifos'), array('*', 'date'=>'DATE(t.created_at)'))
                -> join(array('u'=>'users'), 'u.id=t.users_id', array('username', 'avatar'))
                -> where('status = ?', $status)
                -> order('likes DESC')
                -> limit(10, 0);

// die((string)$oS); //execute sql in mysql client, pma and checks if it is correct

$tifos = $model->fetchAll($oS);
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't really get it. Where should I put it?:>

Comment: I seperate creating SQL bject from querying and fetching. Uncomment die() to see created SQL and execute it in PMA

Comment: Alright, it should build a query like this:

SELECT *, DATE(t.created_at) as date FROM tifos as t JOIN users as u ON t.users_id = u.id WHERE t.status = 'ok' ORDER BY t.likes DESC LIMIT 0,10;

Am I right? It gives null in PMA, why? Can't find any mistakes ;p

Comment: Two reasons possible: status (you should prepend table alias), join try to find manually provided SQL

Comment: OK, this is what I get now:

SELECT `t`.*, DATE(t.created_at) AS `date`, `u`.`username`, `u`.`avatar` FROM `tifos` AS `t` INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON u.id=t.users_id WHERE (t.status = 'ok') ORDER BY `likes` DESC LIMIT 10

Still returns nothing o_O

Comment: There are no information about db structure, so cant help. Moreover it's not matter of ORM, ZF or even PHP rather than dtat and db struct. Please add another question fully documented.